# Trying to understand the Jacobian, part I.

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

So I am trying to understand the Jacobian, as it relates to the transformation of random variables. The nuts and bolts are buried in calculus however.

Now, I have been reading this [paper](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/courses/st309-larget/jacobian.pdf) here, and I have some 'nested' questions so please bear with me.

**Question 1)** (Page 1): It says that:

> "If h is differentiable, the approximation $h(x + dx) \approx h(x) + h'(x)dx$".

Why is this the case? I have 'accepted' it but I would like to know why it's true, although it does not affect question (2) directly for me.

**Question 2:** (Page 2): (This is my main question): Towards the bottom, the author uses a, b, c and d as placeholders for partial derivatives. I am clear as to everything as to how he got there, up until where he puts the a,b,c and d into that mini table with the arrows. I am convinced that in the table, he has mixed up b with c. For example, he has written that:

$$ 
(x_1 + dx_1, x_2) \rightarrow (y_1 + a, y_2 + b)
$$

I am conivinced that the 'b' should actually be a 'c', going by his own definition. So what I think it should read instead is:

$$ 
(x_1 + dx_1, x_2) \rightarrow (y_1 + a, y_2 + c)
$$

My reasoning is as follows. For the first part, ($y_1 + a$), we can get it as so:

$$ h_1(x_1 + dx_1, x_2) \approx h_1(x_1,x_2) + \frac{\delta h_1(x_1,x_2)}{\delta x_1} dx_1 + 0
$$

This yields, by his own definition:

$$
h_1(x_1 + dx_1, x_2) \approx y_1 + a
$$

So far so good. So similarly, for the second coordinate of the transformed point, I reason as such:

$$
h_2(x_1 + dx_1, x_2) \approx h_2(x_1,x_2) + \frac{\delta h_2(x_1,x_2)}{\delta x_1} dx_1 + 0
$$

So this then, by his own definitions, must be:

$$
h_2(x_1 + dx_1, x_2) \approx y_2 + c
$$

So why is it written as 'b' instead? b is as partial derivative of $h_1$ w.r.t $x_2$, whence in fact we are in actuality deriving $h_2$ w.r.t $x_1$. $x_1$ is the only thing that is varying, and the second coordinate of this point is a function of $h_2$. So what gives? Is this a typo in the paper or have I missed something completely?

Some context: I currently understand the random variable $y_1$ to be created as a linear combination of the r.v.'s $x_1$ and $x_2$, through transformation $h_1$. Similarly, r.v. $y_2$ is created as a linear combo of r.v.'s $x_1$ and $x_2$, through transformation $h_2$.

Comment: For (1), look at the finite difference approximation.

$f'(x) \equiv \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$.

Now, use a limit argument to get to dx.

Comment: @EdGorcenski Ah yes! Its from the derivative argument. Got it thanks!

Comment: My comment should have an approx sign, not an equiv sign.

Comment: @EdGorcenski Any idea on question (2) ... ?

Comment: Perhaps. I do not have sufficient interest to read an understand the background of the article you linked, but I will attempt a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though you have a vector-valued function $\mathbf{h}(\cdot)$ of a vector: $\mathbf{h}\ :\ \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$.

In single-variable calculus, we learn of derivatives: $f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$ and approximation via finite differences: $f(x+\Delta x) \approx f(x)+\Delta xf'(x)$.

Now, let's generalize that to multivariable calculus.

Let's say we want to find $\mathbf{h}(\mathbf{x})$ using finite difference schemes. Uh oh, how do we handle this with vectors? The answer is using the Jacobian, which is a matrix that contains the partial derivatives of each element of $\mathbf{h}$ with respect to each coordinate in $\mathbf{x}$.

Therefore, we can write $\mathbf{h}(\mathbf{x}+\Delta \mathbf{x}) \approx \mathbf{h} + J\Delta \mathbf{x}$.

$\Delta \mathbf{x}$ is a vector, and we expect the Jacobian $J$ to be a matrix.

Specifically, what we have is

$J = \left( \begin{array}{cc} \frac{\partial h_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial h_1}{\partial x_2} \\ \frac{\partial h_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial h_2}{\partial x_2} \end{array}\right)$.

When you compute the finite difference update above, you have to perform the matrix vector multiplication, which should give you:

$h_1(\mathbf{x}+\Delta \mathbf{x}) = x_1+\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial x_1}\Delta x_1+\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial x_2}\Delta x_2,$

$h_2(\mathbf{x}+\Delta \mathbf{x}) = x_2+\frac{\partial h_2}{\partial x_1}\Delta x_1+\frac{\partial h_2}{\partial x_2}\Delta x_2.$

Does this help clarify the question a bit?

Comment: I believe so yes. So, if we have a square in the old space, it becomes a parralellogram in the new space. Each of the 4 points is transformed to a new point. In order to be able to tell how, say, the transformer $h_1$ gives you a new ordinate $y_1$, we hold down $x_2$ and dither $x_1$, and then hold down $x_1$ and dither $x_2$. We do the same for $h_2$. So this is what the partials in the Jacobian are capturing, yes?

Comment: Yes. If you had a vector, say $\mathbf{x} = (a, a)^T$, then it would "define" a square. The Jacobian update step would transform that to a parallelogram.